# PayPal SDK - TEMPLATE_ID_INVALID

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

What does `TEMPLATE_ID_INVALID` mean? Why does the following code fail? .

```
$apiContext=getApiContext();
$agreement = new Agreement();
$agreement->setName("name")
->setDescription("descr")
->setStartDate( date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s",strtotime("+1 days"))."Z"  );
$plan = new Plan();
$plan->setId($planid);
$agreement->setPlan($plan);

$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
$agreement->setPayer($payer);

try {
 $agreement = $agreement->create($apiContext);
 $approvalUrl = $agreement->getApprovalLink();
} catch (Exception $ex) {

}
```

Exception `$ex` is:

```
  PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException object {
  url => (string) https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/
  data => (string) {"name":"TEMPLATE_ID_INVALID","details":[{"field":"template id is invalid","issue":"Incorrect Template Id."}],"message":"","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#TEMPLATE_ID_INVALID","debug_id":"fdf8520bc9574"}
  message => (string) Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. `$planid` had the wrong value. The right plan id must look like: `'P-86531922WW564673NESSWCCA'`.